# ffmpeg concat and scale simultaneously?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I have two `ffmpeg` commands:

> `ffmpeg -i d:\1.mp4 -i d:\1.mp4  -filter_complex "[0:0] [0:1] [1:0] [1:1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]"  -map "[v]" -map "[a]"   d:\3.mp4`

and

> `ffmpeg -i  d:\1.mp4 -vf scale=320:240  d:\3.mp4`

How to use them both simultaneously?

Comment: Very thanks, I was missed wisdom about superuser.com. But I'll reply this q, because I found working solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i d:\1.mp4 -i d:\2.mp4 -filter_complex "concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]; \
[v]scale=320:200[v2]" -map "[v2]" -map "[a]" d:\3.mp4
```

Firstly we concatenate everything and pipe result to `[v]` `[a]` (see [filtergraph syntax docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1) - its output from [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) filter). Next we take `[v]`, scale it and output to `[v2]`, lastly we take `[v2]` and `[a]` and mux it to `d:\3.mp4` file.

Comment: I tried the same; `ffmpeg -i video720p.mp4 -i video1080p.mp4 -filter_complex "concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]; \
[v]scale=1280:720[v2]" -map "[v2]" -map "[a]" videoResult.mp4`

 But I get  this error:  `Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 1920x1080, SAR 0:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1280x720, SAR 0:1)
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 0x1e2d1a0] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_0`

Comment: Same error here as @Mikel

Answer (score 26):

**For posterity:**
The accepted answer does not work if the input sources are of different sizes (which is the primary reason why you need to scale before combining).

What you need to do is to first scale and then pipe that video output into the concat filter like so:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=1024:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=1[v0]; \ 
 [1:v]scale=1024:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=1[v1]; \
 [v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map [v] -map [a] output.mp4
```

Had this problem today and was pulling my hair for good three hours trying to figure this out and unfortunately the accepted answer did not work as noted in the comments.

Comment: Can I scale the second video according to the first video dimensions  , since I have various  videos and I want to add simple image into at the first .

Answer (score 0):

Construct custom filtergraph, move resize procedure nearer to the video source, for example let's deal with a more complex graph in order to grasp the spirit of its construction language:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i Movie_oriented_minus_90.mov -i Movie_pause.mp4 -i Sound_pause.aac -filter_complex "[0:v:0]scale=1920:1080 [c1],[c1]vflip[c2],[c2]hflip[clip], [clip] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [2:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -q:v 0 -acodec mp3 -s 1920x1080 Movie_oriented_plus_90_with_pause.mp4
```

- Stage 1: Movie_oriented_minus_90 is source 0, its video stream
  **[0:v:0]** fed into scale filter and produced as **[c1]**, then **[c1]** flipped
  vertically into **[c2]** and then **[c2]** flipped horizontally into **[clip]**
  thus rotated for 180 degree
- Stage 2: 1st video stream concatenated with 2nd source stream, i.e.
  1st video stream: **[clip]** (processed stream from source 0) and sound
  from original video **[0:a:0]** 2nd video stream: constructed from video
  from source 1 **[1:v:0]** and audio **[2:a:0]** from source 2 (30 sec of
  silence made with *-filter_complex "aevalsrc=0:d=30"* during separated
  run of ffmpeg)
- Stage 3: the resulting video sequence **[v]** and **[a]** then compressed
  with *x264* codec into the target *mp4* file

So, the main problem with your question was that you tried to concatenate streams with dfferent sizes and only then applied resizing operation for the already aggregated stream which is of course can't consist of media samples with different sizes.