# ffmpeg - Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 640x640, SAR 16:9) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (640x640, SAR 427:240)

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to concat 4 mp4 files. I'm using the command below but not able to concat

```
ffmpeg -i new1.mp4 -i new2.mp4 -i new3.mp4 -i new4.mp4 -filter_complex concat=n=4:v=1:a=1 output.mp4
```

Getting this error :

```
Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 640x640, SAR 16:9) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (640x640, SAR 427:240)
```

All four vides has the same codec and same size (640x640) and the same bitrate (30)

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The inputs don't have identical sample aspect ratios. Try

```
ffmpeg -i new1.mp4 -i new2.mp4 -i new3.mp4 -i new4.mp4 -filter_complex \
        "[0]setdar=16/9[a];[1]setdar=16/9[b];[2]setdar=16/9[c];[3]setdar=16/9[d]; \
         [a][b][c][d]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1" output.mp4
```

Comment: It works great thank you. But please can you give me an advice how to set scale in the same code here is the code not working :  ffmpeg -i new1.mp4 -i new2.mp4 -i new3.mp4 -i new4.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]setdar=16/9:scale=640x640[a];[1]setdar=16/9:scale=640x640[b];[2]setdar=16/9:scale=640x640[c];[3]setdar=16/9:scale=640x640[d]; [a][b][c][d] concat=n=4:v=1" output.mp4

Comment: it should be `scale=640x640,setdar=16/9` -- reverse order and comma, not colon.

Comment: Can you please help me about bitrate of audio? ...[0]setdar=16/9,rate=30[a]... not working? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to concat videos with sound, Using a:1 option like this : ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -i 4.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]setdar=16/9,scale=640x640[a];[1]setdar=16/9,scale=640x640[b];[2]setdar=16/9,scale=640x640[c];[3]setdar=16/9,scale=640x640[d]; [a][b][c][d] concat=n=4:v=1:a=1" output.mp4
But getting this error :  Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_scale_3' filter output pad 0 (video) and the 'Parsed_concat_8' filter input pad 1 (audio) It is about bitrate I think.

Comment: No. You need to feed the audio streams to the concat: `[a][0:a][b][1:a][c][2:a][d][3:a] concat=n=4:v=1:a=1[v][a]` and then map the output `-map "[v]" -map "[a]"`

Comment: Hello @Mulvya i have same issue media type mismatch can you please help me out .

Comment: @KarandeepAtwal Post it as new question with command and full console output.

Comment: @Mulvya I need help link - https://superuser.com/questions/1210518/ffmpeg-library-for-merging-videos-in-android-takes-very-much-time

Comment: This only worked for me when the aspect ratios matched.

Comment: Yes, technically, the SARs need to be equal. Equal DAR will lead to equal SAR only when the resolutions all match.

Comment: @Gyan Could you explain how to combine the command in your answer with the one mapping audio in your comment above? The current answer's command isn't helpful because it doesn't take into account the audio streams that most videos have, and complex filters feel like black magic as it is.

Comment: @HashimAziz Assuming all inputs have audio, change the last filter to `[a][0:a][b][1:a][c][2:a][d][3:a]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1`

Comment: ffmpeg was stuck in a loop and outputting a garbage video, due to the different input video framerates, but noting the "Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it." and taking its suggestion to add "-vsync 2" did the trick to produce a nice final video!

Comment: for newbies like me, here's the final command which worked for me
`ffmpeg -i v11.mp4 -i v22.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]setdar=16/9[a];[1]setdar=16/9[b]; [a][0:a][b][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" -vsync 2 output.mp4`

Comment: how to apply withou audio?

Comment: Add `-an` before output.mp4 and change to `a=0` in concat filter.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one more simple way https://stackoverflow.com/a/48853654/6465520

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1024:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=1[v0]; [1:v]scale=1024:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=1[v1]; [v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map [v] -map [a] output.mp4
```

So, first you scale all input videos to the same resolution and then concatenate them.

**UPD**

The answer above does not work for videos with different aspect ratio. I constructed another filter, which first scales the videos to the desired resolution, adding a black padding if necessary, and then concats them:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -n -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:eval=frame,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black[v0]; [1:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:eval=frame,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black[v1]; [v0][0:a][v1][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map [v] -map [a] -s hd720 -vcodec libx264 result1.mp4
```

Comment: I had it first like that but even if the scales are shown as equal the SAR values can mismatch. I got an error "Input link in0:v0 parameters (size 1280x720, SAR 9:8) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1280x720, SAR 5751:5120)". The answer of Gyan above with both settings "scale=1280x720,setdar=1280/720" solved it.

Answer (score 0):

[@maksim-vorontsov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6465520/maksim-vorontsov)'s answer for different aspect ratios was so good (and I needed to do this to a lot of videos with arbitrary inputs) that I made a bash script out of it to allow concatenation and resizing of arbitrary set of input videos into a final output:

https://gist.github.com/mkatychev/c1edf136ad36bc137134d098198903b3

the core `ffmpeg` argbuilder is the function below:

```bash
join_files() {
  local input_n=()
  local scale_to_n=("$SEP")
  local concat_n=()
  for i in $(seq $#); do
    input_n+=("-i ${!i}")
    ((n = i - 1))

    concat_n+=("[v${n}][${n}:a]")

    local scale_to=""
    scale_to+="[${n}:v]scale=$SCALE:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:eval=frame,"
    scale_to+="pad=$SCALE:-1:-1:color=black[v${n}];$SEP"
    scale_to_n+=("$scale_to")
  done
  local filter_complex=""
  filter_complex+="${scale_to_n[*]}"
  filter_complex+="${concat_n[*]}"
  filter_complex+=" concat=n=$#:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]"
  # shellcheck disable=SC2068
  command $FFMPEG ${input_n[@]} -n -filter_complex "$filter_complex" \
    -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -s hd480 -vcodec libx264 "$OUT_FILE"
}
```

Running with `--debug` flag:

```
$ ./ffmpeg_concat_and_scale.sh video_1.mp4 video_2.flv video_3.mp4 video_4.flv --scale 640:480 --debug --out video_1_to_4.mkv

ffmpeg -i video_1.mp4 -i video_2.flv -i video_3.mp4 -i video_4.flv -n -filter_complex
 [0:v]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:eval=frame,pad=640:480:-1:-1:color=black[v0];
 [1:v]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:eval=frame,pad=640:480:-1:-1:color=black[v1];
 [2:v]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:eval=frame,pad=640:480:-1:-1:color=black[v2];
 [3:v]scale=640:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease:eval=frame,pad=640:480:-1:-1:color=black[v3];
[v0][0:a] [v1][1:a] [v2][2:a] [v3][3:a] concat=n=4:v=1:a=1 [v] [a] -map [v] -map [a] -s hd480 -vcodec libx264 video_1_to_4.mkv
```

Remove `--debug` to create `video_1_to_4.mkv`:

```bash
./ffmpeg_concat_and_scale.sh video_1.mp4 video_2.flv video_3.mp4 video_4.flv --scale 640:480 --out video_1_to_4.mkv
```