# Concatenating two videos with different width and height

Tags: video, ffmpeg, libav

If i try to concatenate two videos it throws an error due to different screen sizes of the videos. I have put a setdat=16/9 parameter like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327163/ffmpeg-input-link-in1v0-parameters-size-640x640-sar-169-do-not-match-the) for each two video. Then i got the error below. How can i concatenate two videos with different screen sizes?

code:

```
ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/GetVideo/reklam/muzikli1.mp4 -i /var/www/html/GetVideo/tempvideo/sample.mp4 -filter_complex \ "[0]setdar=16/9[a];[1]setdar=16/9[b]; \ [a][b]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" /var/www/html/GetVideo/reklam/out.mp4
```

error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/html/GetVideo $ ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/GetVideo/reklam/muzikli1.mp4 -i /var/www/html/GetVideo/tempvideo/sample.mp4 -filter_complex \ "[0]setdar=16/9[a];[1]setdar=16/9[b]; \ [a][b]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" /var/www/html/GetVideo/reklam/out.mp4
ffmpeg version git-2018-05-06-652b857 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      56. 18.100 / 56. 18.100
  libavcodec     58. 19.101 / 58. 19.101
  libavformat    58. 13.101 / 58. 13.101
  libavdevice    58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100
  libavfilter     7. 21.100 /  7. 21.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/html/GetVideo/reklam/muzikli1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
  Duration: 00:00:13.35, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 244 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 918x512 [SAR 1:1 DAR 459:256], 110 kb/s, 5 fps, 5 tbr, 5k tbn, 10k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/var/www/html/GetVideo/tempvideo/sample.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.65.100
  Duration: 00:00:25.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1015 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 896 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 113 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x2fa9a20] No such filter: ' '
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

Comment: Videos need to have same dimensions and SAR for concat. You can always add `unsafe=1` to the filter but not recommended as results are unpredictable.

Comment: @Gyan My videos have different dimensions. How can i make them same?