# ffmpeg use setdar in filter

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

As described already here [ffpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327163/ffmpeg-input-link-in1v0-parameters-size-640x640-sar-169-do-not-match-the) I get an error when using this command

```
ffmpeg -i 234627426842_converted.mp4 -i 1548625936003_converted.mp4 -i 1548626656821_converted.mp4 -i 1548625467753_converted.mp4 -c:a aac -strict -2 -filter_complex [0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0][3:v:0][3:a:0]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1[v][a] -map [v] -map [a] ready.mp4
```

in order to concentrate 4 different videos. However, I cant add setdar=16/9 to the filter as said in the accepted answer of the previously mentioned question because my filter looks like this:

```
[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0][3:v:0][3:a:0]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1[v][a]
```

How can I add setdar=16/9 to every video stream using this layout? (Im new to ffmpeg)

Comment: The linked answer still applies. Replace `[0:v:0]` with `[a]`, `[1:v:0]` with `[b]` and so on, after adding the setdar filters before, as shown there.

Comment: So e.g. like this:

ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -i 4.mp4 -i 5.mp5 -async 1 -vsync 1 -c:a aac -strict -2 -filter_complex [0]setdar=16/9[a];[1]setdar=16/9[b];[2]setdar=16/9[c];[3]setdar=16/9[d];[4]setdar=16/9[e];[5]setdar=16/9[f];[b][c][d][e][f]concat=n=6:v=1:a=1[v][a] ready.mp4

?